# How to hide price for guest users in magento2

Tags: magento-2.1, price

How to hide the price for all user after login they can see price for all products.
i am using this code:

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox" type="Vendor\Module\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox" />
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Pricing/Render/FinalPriceBox.php

```
protected function wrapResult($html)
{
    $active = $this->_dataHelper->getIsActive();
    $hidePrice = $this->getSaleableItem()->getHidePrice();
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager $om */
    $om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $context */
    $context = $om->get('Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context');
    /** @var bool $isLoggedIn */
    $isLoggedIn = $context->getValue(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH
    );
    $currentCustomerGroupId = $this->customerSession
        ->getcustomer_group_id();
    $hideByCustomerGroup = $this->_dataHelper->getHideByCustomerGroup();

    if ($hideByCustomerGroup != 0) {
        $disableCustomerId = $this->_dataHelper->getCustomerGroupId();
        $disableCustIdArray = explode(",", $disableCustomerId);
    }

    $hideProductByCustGroup = $this->getSaleableItem()
        ->getHidepriceByCustomergroup();

    if (!empty($hideProductByCustGroup)) {
        $hideProductByCustGroupArray = explode(",", $hideProductByCustGroup);
    }

    if ($active) {
        if ($isLoggedIn) {
            if ($hideByCustomerGroup == 1) {
                if (!empty($hideProductByCustGroup)) {
                    if (in_array($currentCustomerGroupId, $hideProductByCustGroupArray)) {
                        return '<div class="price-box ' .
                        $this->getData('css_classes') . '" ' .
                        'data-role="priceBox" ' . 'data-product-id="' .
                        $this->getSaleableItem()->getId() . '"' .
                        '>' . $html . '</div>';
                    } else {
                        return '<div class="price-box ' .
                        $this->getData('css_classes') . '" ' .
                        'data-role="priceBox" ' .
                        'data-product-id="' .
                        $this->getSaleableItem()->getId() . '"' .
                        '><a href="' .
                        $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl() .
                        $this->_dataHelper->getLinkUrl() . '">' .
                        $this->_dataHelper->getDisplayText() .
                        '</a></div>';
                    }
                } else {
                    if (in_array($currentCustomerGroupId, $disableCustIdArray)) {
                        return '<div class="price-box ' .
                        $this->getData('css_classes') . '" ' .
                        'data-role="priceBox" ' .
                        'data-product-id="' .
                        $this->getSaleableItem()->getId() . '"' .
                        '><a href="' . $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl() .
                        $this->_dataHelper->getLinkUrl() . '">' .
                        $this->_dataHelper->getDisplayText() .
                        '</a></div>';
                    } else {
                        return '<div class="price-box ' .
                        $this->getData('css_classes') . '" ' .
                        'data-role="priceBox" ' .
                        'data-product-id="' .
                        $this->getSaleableItem()->getId() . '"' .
                        '>' . $html . '</div>';
                    }
                }
            } else {
                return '<div class="price-box ' .
                $this->getData('css_classes') . '" ' .
                'data-role="priceBox" ' .
                'data-product-id="' .
                $this->getSaleableItem()->getId() . '"' .
                '>' . $html . '</div>';
            }
        } else {
            if ($hidePrice != 0) {
                return '<div class="price-box ' .
                $this->getData('css_classes') . '" ' .
                'data-role="priceBox" ' .
                'data-product-id="' . $this->getSaleableItem()->getId() .
                '"' . '><a href="' .
                $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl() .
                $this->_dataHelper->getLinkUrl() . '">' .
                $this->_dataHelper->getDisplayText() .
                '</a></div>';
            } else {
                return '<div class="price-box ' .
                $this->getData('css_classes') . '" ' .
                'data-role="priceBox" ' .
                'data-product-id="' .
                $this->getSaleableItem()->getId() . '"' .
                '>' . $html . '</div>';
            }
        }
    } else {
        return '<div class="price-box ' .
        $this->getData('css_classes') . '" ' .
        'data-role="priceBox" ' .
        'data-product-id="' . $this->getSaleableItem()->getId() .
        '"' . '>' . $html . '</div>';
    }
}
```

It is not working.

Comment: I think you should use plugin. I've done it before, but I forgot to save my code :)

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for a proven solution you can try extension:
https://codecanyon.net/item/hide-price-magento-2-extension/20334355

I use and work perfectly.